# Flush-mountable smart light remote switch - Replacement for Lutron Connected Bulb Remote?

Tags: zigbee, smart-lights, philips-hue, zwave

The Lutron Connected Bulb Remote was a great little light switch that could be flush mounted in a US style switch plate for a professional look. It was discontinued in 2018 or so.

[image]

Hue has the [Smart Wireless Dimmer Switch and Remote,](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-dimmer-switch/046677473372) but it mounts on top of its own custom plate and a) doesn't look as professional, and b) can't integrate with other existing switches in a two or three gang plate.

Friends of Hue has a [switch by RunLessWire](https://runlesswire.com/click_philips_hue/) that uses a battery-free mechanism to generate electricity, but I find that click feels cheap and would vastly prefer a battery solution.

There are plenty of wired solutions, but I don't need to control wired lighting.

**Is there another remote out there that can control Philips Hue that is also mountable inside a light switch cover?** If not for Hue, are there any for Z-wave?

Comment: You could probably 3D print a plate for the Hue Dimmer switch so it can be recessed into the plate? Have you compared the sizes of the Hue switch with your existing one? If smaller you could just have a small “adapter” maybe...

Comment: There are literally tons of 3D models of plates and adapters of all sorts for the Hue Dimmer Switch out there, but all those I found are still mounted on top of the existing plate rather that in its place. They might a tad tall to fit in between the screws that should be present underneath your plate, so it might not be that easy to build a model that doesn't stick out of the wall. Note that a new version is coming very soon, don't know if the dimensions changed.

Comment: I believe the dimensions of the new one are the same